# Encrypting and decrypting AWS secret/access keys using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am copying data from a S3 bucket to a table in Redshift. For this, I require my AWS secret and access keys in the code but I want to avoid doing that. Hence, I need to encrypt and then decrypt them. I would really like to know a way of doing this in Python.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking us to give you Python code? (This might be too broad) Or are you asking how to handle a secret access key in AWS?

Comment: I'm asking how to handle a secret access key in AWS while doing the task mentioned above in Python. I can write up the code. Just need to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running over amazon instances you not need to pass the keys you can create and application role for that for more information see this doc

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using an EC2 instance for this (not given access).